# Unable to delete event instance in a recurring event based on RDATE

Tags: google-calendar-api

I'm experiencing issues with the Google Calendar API.

When deleting an **event instance** that instance belongs to a recurring event made from an RDATE I never get consistent answers of if it is deleted (read "cancelled") or not.

From my experience the after **event instance** is deleted via the API the status becomes "cancelled" as you would expect. But I can only see/confirm this if I do an API GET call.

If I do an Google API List call (getting all the instances) show the status is always "confirmed" and the event instance appears whether or not showDeleted is true or false.

Also if I do an API instances call on the master recurring event... they all show "confirmed"... none display "cancelled"... yet I know I deleted one and GET gets the result.

Does anyone else have this issue? Or have a solution. (and EXDATE is out...as I don't affect other event instance data stored which gets wiped if I change the recurring rule...)

Comment: Instances call will skip deleted instances. You will need to set showDeleted=true on the instances call to see the deleted one.

Comment: Thanks @luc  actually the problem is that I am seeing the deleted items regardless of any parameters like showDeleted. Any deleted items are always returned on INSTANCES or QUERY ... and they have a status set to "confirmed". The only time we get any sense of the item being deleted is when we retrieve the item through a GET and it has a status of "cancelled" or we try and modify the item (which results in an error - "item is deleted")

Comment: That should not be the case. Deleted items should have status confirmed (should have cancelled). Instances should not return deleted items unless you specify showDeleted=true. Would you mind pasting here the recurrence rule of the recurring event, which instance you deleted (and whether through the API or through calendar web UI) and what instances gave you back?

Comment: `// Master event with RDATE rule
{

   "kind": "calendar#event",
   "id": "cnt0tq3o0n78h6agmspni8q2a0",
   "status": "confirmed",
   "recurrence": [
 "RDATE;TZID=Australia/Sydney:20140717T000000,20140724T000000,20140731T000000,20140807T000000,20140814T000000"
   ],  
 }`

Comment: SEARCH RESULT same as INSTANCES


`{

   "kind": "calendar#event",
   "etag": "\"2833762199988000\"",
   "id": "cnt0tq3o0n78h6agmspni8q2a0_20140716T140000Z",
   "status": "confirmed",
   "start": {
    "date": "2014-07-16"
   },
   "end": {
    "date": "2014-07-16"
   },
   "recurringEventId": "cnt0tq3o0n78h6agmspni8q2a0"
   }`

Comment: // RESULT shows cancelled
`{

 "kind": "calendar#event",
 "etag": "\"2859013808676000\"",
 "id": "cnt0tq3o0n78h6agmspni8q2a0_20140716T140000Z",
 "status": "cancelled",
 "start": {
  "date": "2014-07-16"
 },
 "end": {
  "date": "2014-07-16"
 },
 "recurringEventId": "cnt0tq3o0n78h6agmspni8q2a0",
 }
}`

Comment: Thanks @luc for responding. We don't know what to do about these items. As you can see the caledar event has an RDATE rule... the search result returns 5 entires regardless if "deleted" or not... (I've only shown 1 item)... and if i GET that one item the result shows cancelled.

Comment: So I created a recurring event doing: POST https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/primary/events?key={YOUR_API_KEY}
 
{
 "end": {
  "timeZone": "Australia/Sydney",
  "dateTime": "2014-07-17T00:00:00"
 },
 "start": {
  "timeZone": "Australia/Sydney",
  "dateTime": "2014-07-17T00:00:00"
 },
 "recurrence": [
  "RDATE;TZID=Australia/Sydney:20140717T000000,20140724T000000,20140731T000000,20140807T000000,20140814T000000"
 ],
 "summary": "weird recurring"
} and then deleted the instance you mentioned via web UI. It's no longer showing in the instances call..